# Short Story about a cultist/servant of the gods of the road/cars/oil, who goes around stopping the development of safer, more efficient cars

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The idea is that the gods feed on the blood sacrifice of people and animals who die on the road. They healed or resurrected the main character to be their mortal instrument to keep the blood flowing, and so he goes around stopping the development of safer, more efficient cars.

At the end we see his office where he's hung all the parts of the car that he was in during his accident around his office, like the viscera of a hated foe.

I read this more than three years ago, but less than ten. I remember reading it online, but I believe it was published somewhere, as opposed to a random
Tumblr post or something.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you read this?

Comment: Thanks, I read it more than 3 years ago but less than 10 (not much help sorry). And I remember reading it online but I believe it was published somewhere as opposed to like a random tumbler post or something.